# Signification de « tant »

Tags: grammaire, sens, adverbes

Quelqu'un pourrait-il m'expliquer ce que veut dire la phrase suivante ?

> Pierre est parfois amené à regretter certaines décisions qu’il prend
>   tant il est impatient.

Quelle est la signification de *tant* dans ce contexte ? Je sais que *tant* peut exprimer une grande importance, intensité, quantité ou une quantité indéterminée, mais je ne vois pas comment cela convient dans cette phrase. Est-ce qu'il est si impatient qu'il prend des décisions qu'il regrette plus tard ou bien s'agit-il d'autre chose ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Un autre terme qui aurait pu être utilisé à la place de "tant" est "tellement" (ou "si" comme vous l'avez suggéré):

> Pierre est parfois amené à regretter certaines décisions qu’il prend
>   tellement il est impatient.
>
> Pierre est si impatient qu'il est parfois amené à regretter certaines
>   décisions prises.

Je trouve que le sens de la phrase est alors bien plus clair:

> L'impatience de Pierre le pousse à prendre certaines décisions qu'il
>   regrette ensuite.

Comment: «Si» offre en effet parfois une possibilité de remplacer «tant» et «tellement». Mais pas ici, à moins d’une restructuration majeure de la phrase, comme ce fut le cas pour la suggestion de l'OP.

Comment: @Montéedelait Effectivement, la phrase doit être restructurée si on utilise "si". Je vais modifier ma réponse.

Answer (score 0):

« Tant » exprime l'intensité ; on peut le remplacer par « si » ; seulement il faut changer un peu l'ordre des mots et ajouter un complément, l'ajout de ce complément amenant un certain support à ce qui est expliqué après cette reformulation ;

- Pierre est parfois amené à regretter certaines décisions si impatient est-il en les prenant.

> (TLFi) 3. [Tant introd. une prop. à valeur causale ou justificative]
>   a) [La sub. causale peut se trouver à différents endroits de la phrase]
>
> [En seconde place, après l'énoncé de l'effet]
>
> - Elle n'osait pas pleurer, tant elle avait peur de la Thénardier.
> - J'eus de la peine à le reconnaître tant avait maigri son grand corps, déjà mince et frêle naguère.

Comme je la conçoit cette phrase (phrase initiale) est mal construite du point de vue style, bien que parfaitement correcte grammaticalement;  on comprend l'idée et elle s'exprime de façon plus clairement conséquentielle de la façon suivante bien que ce résultat ne soit qu'une amélioration;

- Pierre est amené à regretter certaines décisions qu'il prend tant il est impatient de les avoir faites.

On comprend plus clairement que la conséquence de décisions rapides est l'erreur ou de façon équivalente que la cause de l'erreur est la décision rapide. Il est parfaitement explicite dans la formulation suivante que la cause n'est plus l'impatience mais la décision trop rapide due à l'impatience ;

- Pierre est amené à regretter certaines décisions qu'il prend tant son impatience en fait des décision rapides.

Dans la phrase initiale il est donc nécessaire d'extrapoler mentalement sur le concept et de déduire que par « impatience » on signifie une action ou un état qui en découle et on choisi (arbitrairement) l'action de la décision trop rapide.

L'excès d'impatience cause-t-il d'amener Pierre à regretter des décisions ? Certainement pas, c'est l'erreur qui l'amène à regretter les décisions. Indirectement, c'est vrai, mais la causalité directe manque and on n'est pas tout à fait sûr. Tout aussi bien on peut interpréter la phrase comme suit ;

- Pierre est parfois amené à regretter certaines décisions qu’il prend tant il est impatient *de constater des résultats qui ne viennent que lentement*.

Pourquoi doit-on obligatoirement penser que s'il n'y a pas de complément il s'agit nécessairement du complément sous-entendu « de les avoir faites » ? C'est ce qui rend l'énonciation désagréable, et cela même dans un contexte étranger à l'ambiguïté.

Comment: *Comme je la conçoit cette phrase (phrase initiale) est mal construite du point de vue style* La preuve par l'exemple...